# FindShortestTour 3D data

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, distance

I would like to plot a line in 3D with the following set of (x,y,z) data points:

```
zeroth={{0.198494, 1.0698, 0.}, {0.198494, 1.0698, 0.}, {0.322084, 0.942887, 
  0.}, {0.322084, 0.942887, 0.}, {0.57675, 0.374922, 0.}, {0.57675, 
  0.374922, 0.}, {0.185552, 1.08436, 0.0174533}, {0.21515, 
  1.04994, -0.0174533}, {0.294367, 0.969347, -0.0174533}, {0.34339, 
  0.92289, 0.0174533}, {0.572446, 0.382744, -0.0174533}, {0.580764, 
  0.366278, 0.0174533}, {0.17605, 1.0959, 0.0349066}, {0.361884, 
  0.905559, 0.0349066}, {0.568021, 0.390999, -0.0349066}, {0.584708, 
  0.358305, 0.0349066}, {0.167861, 1.10553, 0.0523599}, {0.378751, 
  0.888973, 0.0523599}, {0.563454, 0.398726, -0.0523599}, {0.588342, 
  0.34942, 0.0523599}, {0.160579, 1.11425, 0.0698132}, {0.394408, 
  0.873581, 0.0698132}, {0.558652, 0.406566, -0.0698132}, {0.59183, 
  0.341176, 0.0698132}, {0.154665, 1.12179, 0.0872665}, {0.408502, 
  0.859143, 0.0872665}, {0.553815, 0.414281, -0.0872665}, {0.595093, 
  0.332111, 0.0872665}, {0.148905, 1.12994, 0.10472}, {0.422286, 
  0.844652, 0.10472}, {0.548771, 0.421794, -0.10472}, {0.598436, 
  0.324043, 0.10472}, {0.143945, 1.13674, 0.122173}, {0.435713, 
  0.830522, 0.122173}, {0.543751, 0.429605, -0.122173}, {0.601712, 
  0.315436, 0.122173}, {0.13916, 1.14317, 0.139626}, {0.448665, 
  0.816578, 0.139626}, {0.538415, 0.436682, -0.139626}, {0.604995, 
  0.307611, 0.139626}, {0.134868, 1.14949, 0.15708}, {0.461357, 
  0.802559, 0.15708}, {0.533104, 0.444824, -0.15708}, {0.608272, 
  0.299628, 0.15708}, {0.129782, 1.15451, 0.174533}, {0.473408, 
  0.788929, 0.174533}, {0.527582, 0.45209, -0.174533}, {0.61164, 
  0.292204, 0.174533}, {0.126021, 1.16121, 0.191986}, {0.485063, 
  0.775353, 0.191986}, {0.522158, 0.460227, -0.191986}, {0.615157, 
  0.285094, 0.191986}, {0.122085, 1.16774, 0.20944}, {0.496837, 
  0.761577, 0.20944}, {0.516556, 0.467829, -0.20944}, {0.618775, 
  0.278227, 0.20944}, {0.119003, 1.17317, 0.226893}, {0.508827, 
  0.747717, 0.226893}, {0.510879, 0.475897, -0.226893}, {0.622811, 
  0.272617, 0.226893}, {0.116073, 1.17897, 0.244346}, {0.505164, 
  0.484005, -0.244346}, {0.520636, 0.733307, 0.244346}, {0.626954, 
  0.267086, 0.244346}, {0.113093, 1.18503, 0.261799}, {0.499224, 
  0.492086, -0.261799}, {0.532218, 0.719114, 0.261799}, {0.6313, 
  0.261968, 0.261799}, {0.111577, 1.19167, 0.279253}, {0.493298, 
  0.500625, -0.279253}, {0.543953, 0.704469, 0.279253}, {0.636088, 
  0.258389, 0.279253}, {0.108799, 1.1972, 0.296706}, {0.487396, 
  0.508923, -0.296706}, {0.555849, 0.689419, 0.296706}, {0.641129, 
  0.255432, 0.296706}, {0.106535, 1.2035, 0.314159}, {0.481012, 
  0.517715, -0.314159}, {0.568098, 0.674051, 0.314159}, {0.646641, 
  0.253596, 0.314159}, {0.104292, 1.20896, 0.331613}, {0.475234, 
  0.526562, -0.331613}, {0.580646, 0.657968, 0.331613}, {0.65242, 
  0.252806, 0.331613}, {0.102239, 1.21486, 0.349066}, {0.468873, 
  0.535884, -0.349066}, {0.593276, 0.640871, 0.349066}, {0.658571, 
  0.253369, 0.349066}, {0.0982709, 1.22702, 0.383972}, {0.456379, 
  0.554673, -0.383972}, {0.619857, 0.604587, 0.383972}, {0.672131, 
  0.259157, 0.383972}, {0.0965641, 1.23333, 0.401426}, {0.449861, 
  0.56449, -0.401426}, {0.63348, 0.584245, 0.401426}, {0.679381, 
  0.264944, 0.401426}, {0.0950336, 1.23899, 0.418879}, {0.44376, 
  0.574216, -0.418879}, {0.64757, 0.562168, 0.418879}, {0.686969, 
  0.27326, 0.418879}, {0.0935244, 1.24598, 0.436332}, {0.437062, 
  0.58483, -0.436332}, {0.661851, 0.53807, 0.436332}, {0.694583, 
  0.284399, 0.436332}, {0.0921628, 1.25235, 0.453786}, {0.430873, 
  0.594848, -0.453786}, {0.676327, 0.510554, 0.453786}, {0.702176, 
  0.299373, 0.453786}, {0.0909057, 1.25903, 0.471239}, {0.424158, 
  0.605928, -0.471239}, {0.690953, 0.478092, 0.471239}, {0.709389, 
  0.321384, 0.471239}, {0.0893533, 1.26508, 0.488692}, {0.41776, 
  0.61694, -0.488692}, {0.706706, 0.428366, 0.488692}, {0.714591, 
  0.362054, 0.488692}, {0.0882802, 1.27209, 0.506145}, {0.41175, 
  0.627661, -0.506145}, {0.0866466, 1.28613, 0.541052}, {0.398553, 
  0.651324, -0.541052}, {0.0853558, 1.30122, 0.575959}, {0.385974, 
  0.675517, -0.575959}, {0.990179, 0.477353, -0.575959}, {0.0843251, 
  1.31734, 0.610865}, {0.374344, 0.700272, -0.610865}, {0.989617, 
  0.481456, -0.610865}, {0.0837457, 1.334, 0.645772}, {0.36147, 
  0.726643, -0.645772}, {0.638353, 2.23413, 0.645772}, {0.721625, 
  1.67325, 0.645772}, {0.98831, 0.487965, -0.645772}, {0.083432, 
  1.35147, 0.680678}, {0.351011, 0.753154, -0.680678}, {0.614957, 
  2.36198, 0.680678}, {0.738558, 1.56717, 0.680678}, {0.987528, 
  0.496026, -0.680678}, {0.0846713, 1.41083, 0.785398}, {0.32184, 
  0.837719, -0.785398}, {0.55034, 2.62464, 0.785398}, {0.775262, 
  1.36775, 0.785398}, {0.982083, 0.524919, -0.785398}, {0.0886045, 
  1.4721, 0.872665}, {0.300202, 0.91366, -0.872665}, {0.492325, 
  2.76435, 0.872665}, {0.801811, 1.24334, 0.872665}, {0.978066, 
  0.553219, -0.872665}, {0.0959591, 1.54927, 0.959931}, {0.285895, 
  0.991105, -0.959931}, {0.422616, 2.80221, 0.959931}, {0.826049, 
  1.13403, 0.959931}, {0.973523, 0.586711, -0.959931}, {0.0979165, 
  1.56701, 0.977384}, {0.283131, 1.00706, -0.977384}, {0.406624, 
  2.79012, 0.977384}, {0.830947, 1.11328, 0.977384}, {0.973158, 
  0.593456, -0.977384}, {0.100044, 1.58604, 0.994838}, {0.280764, 
  1.02302, -0.994838}, {0.389799, 2.76998, 0.994838}, {0.835528, 
  1.09255, 0.994838}, {0.972037, 0.600484, -0.994838}, {0.102697, 
  1.60734, 1.01229}, {0.278703, 1.03898, -1.01229}, {0.372536, 
  2.74151, 1.01229}, {0.840056, 1.07216, 1.01229}, {0.971291, 
  0.607065, -1.01229}, {0.105605, 1.62932, 1.02974}, {0.277003, 
  1.05492, -1.02974}, {0.354966, 2.70486, 1.02974}, {0.84457, 1.0528, 
  1.02974}, {0.970776, 0.613843, -1.02974}, {0.108686, 1.6531, 
  1.0472}, {0.275683, 1.07085, -1.0472}, {0.337019, 2.65854, 
  1.0472}, {0.849307, 1.03206, 1.0472}, {0.970224, 
  0.620753, -1.0472}, {0.112466, 1.67917, 1.06465}, {0.274745, 
  1.08676, -1.06465}, {0.318697, 2.60254, 1.06465}, {0.853779, 
  1.01239, 1.06465}, {0.9696, 0.627347, -1.06465}, {0.116736, 1.70841,
   1.0821}, {0.274132, 1.10263, -1.0821}, {0.299959, 2.54008, 
  1.0821}, {0.85664, 1.00265, 1.0821}, {0.968657, 
  0.635535, -1.0821}, {0.12178, 1.74126, 1.09956}, {0.27386, 
  1.11846, -1.09956}, {0.281863, 2.47482, 1.09956}, {0.862555, 
  0.974361, 1.09956}, {0.968051, 0.643422, -1.09956}, {0.127955, 
  1.77924, 1.11701}, {0.2626, 2.39964, 1.11701}, {0.273813, 
  1.13432, -1.11701}, {0.866909, 0.954428, 1.11701}, {0.967556, 
  0.649815, -1.11701}, {0.136169, 1.82681, 1.13446}, {0.242183, 
  2.31712, 1.13446}, {0.271801, 1.1507, -1.13446}, {0.871239, 
  0.934992, 1.13446}, {0.966909, 0.65698, -1.13446}, {0.269036, 
  1.18347, -1.16937}, {0.879684, 0.89653, 1.16937}, {0.965879, 
  0.67101, -1.16937}, {0.267177, 1.21624, -1.20428}, {0.887911, 
  0.858914, 1.20428}, {0.965201, 0.684694, -1.20428}, {0.26691, 
  1.2326, -1.22173}, {0.891907, 0.840493, 1.22173}, {0.964468, 
  0.692467, -1.22173}, {0.276434, 1.39499, -1.39626}, {0.928396, 
  0.670141, 1.39626}, {0.960476, 0.764928, -1.39626}, {0.296021, 
  1.55679, -1.5708}, {0.957321, 0.535832, 1.5708}, {0.95374, 
  0.862105, -1.5708}, {0.34458, 1.71073, -1.74533}, {0.936774, 
  1.01638, -1.74533}, {0.979354, 0.440014, 1.74533}, {0.350642, 
  1.72532, -1.76278}, {0.93396, 1.03733, -1.76278}, {0.980757, 
  0.434975, 1.76278}, {0.357762, 1.73963, -1.78024}, {0.930574, 
  1.05985, -1.78024}, {0.98174, 0.431363, 1.78024}, {0.366583, 
  1.75341, -1.79769}, {0.927179, 1.08387, -1.79769}, {0.982802, 
  0.426881, 1.79769}, {0.37735, 1.76655, -1.81514}, {0.92329, 
  1.10887, -1.81514}, {0.984009, 0.422373, 1.81514}, {0.389842, 
  1.77887, -1.8326}, {0.918766, 1.13617, -1.8326}, {0.98526, 0.418057,
   1.8326}, {0.402315, 1.79078, -1.85005}, {0.913131, 
  1.16773, -1.85005}, {0.986116, 0.418629, 1.85005}, {0.418305, 
  1.80127, -1.8675}, {0.907431, 1.19908, -1.8675}, {0.987491, 
  0.415291, 1.8675}, {0.435393, 1.81067, -1.88496}, {0.9006, 
  1.23281, -1.88496}, {0.988555, 0.412967, 1.88496}, {0.456828, 
  1.81772, -1.90241}, {0.893493, 1.26884, -1.90241}, {0.482352, 
  1.82181, -1.91986}, {0.884626, 1.30895, -1.91986}, {0.511384, 
  1.82261, -1.93732}, {0.87373, 1.3539, -1.93732}, {0.547423, 
  1.8171, -1.95477}, {0.859477, 1.4063, -1.95477}, {0.592721, 
  1.80156, -1.97222}, {0.842038, 1.46298, -1.97222}, {0.651874, 
  1.76664, -1.98968}, {0.813639, 1.53909, -1.98968}}
```

Here is a visualization of the points:

```
ListPointPlot3D[zeroth,PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->Black,Boxed->False]
```

[image]

When I try to plot it as a single line I get this nightmare:

```
Graphics3D[{Red,Thick,Line[zeroth]}]
```

[image]

I don't know if there is a way to use the FindShortestTour with this 3D data. I have always used it for 2D data. The only approximate example that I could find in the documentation was example/FindTheShortestTourAroundTheWorld. But that case I think that is less general because there they deal with point in 3D but at the same distance to the origin, which does not apply here.

Comment: looks like your points are in a wrong order. When you plot just points order doesn't matter. When you plot lines the order determines which points are connected together. Even your first 20 points are all over the place `Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, Line[zeroth[[1 ;; 20]]]}, Axes -> True]`

Comment: Oh.. I see now, yes, it seems to work… `Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, 
  Line[zeroth[[FindShortestTour[zeroth][[2]]]]]}]`

Comment: It is the line of zeros of a function of three variables, and I got those points ordered in z. I think that the answer you gave would do the job if I only could choose the ending points. Because it looks like it is connecting some points that I guess that are not connected.

Comment: My guess is that it is a single open line, i.e. with two extrema.

Comment: Can you tell more about the origins of this data? "Line of zerose" of what function? A function f[x,y,z] usually has a surface of zeroes… That you can plot with `ContourPlot3D`

Comment: It is a complex function which depends on three variables, I search the points where the real and imaginary parts of this function vanish in each [x,y] plane for z fix, and I move through the z axis performing this operation. There can be 0, 1, 2 or even 3 zeros in each [x,y] plane. But they all seem to be connected in [x,y,z]

Comment: Can you show us the function? It looks like you are solving a system of two equations with three variables, indeed you should get a curve in 3D in general case.

Comment: These are numerical results. I have 80 3D results, i.e. 80 complex functions in [x,y], and z would be a sort of parameter ( but in fact it is a variable). I am not sure that I could load that amount of data here. The original function lives in five dimensions, but I restrict some of them in order to be able to plot something

Comment: Formatting tip: select the code and press the "Code Sample" button on the toolbar (it looks like `{}`) to format it as a code block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can turn your data into a weighted adjacency graph by using `Outer` and, well, `WeightedAdjacencyGraph`:

```
adjgraph = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[Outer[EuclideanDistance, zeroth, zeroth, 1, 1]];
tour = FindShortestTour[adjgraph];
Show[ListPointPlot3D[zeroth, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Black, Boxed -> False], 
  Graphics3D[{Darker[Red], Line[zeroth[[tour[[2]]]]]}]]
```

[image: connect the dots, la la la la]

Amusingly, it takes longer for Mathematica to actually construct the adjacency matrix on my computer then it does to actually find the tour (0.35 sec vs. 0.055 sec, respectively.)

Comment: I wonder how the endpoints could be identified. In this particular case the "discontinous" derivatives could help

Comment: In this case, a quick & dirty way would be to assume that the two consecutive points with the greatest distance between them are the endpoints.  I like the idea of looking at the angles too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it solved my problem. I think that a three point derivative criterion would be enough because the line is smooth enough except at the endpoints. There is also a restriction on the curve, it cannot go further than x=1. Is there a way to force the program not to connect two specific points?

Comment: If you don't want the resulting tour to contain a link between two particular points $i$ and $j$, set `adjmatrix[[i,j]] = Infinity.`  `FindShortestTour` will still try to find a closed path containing all the points, though;  it just won't connect $i$ to $j$ in the tour.  I don't think there's an easy way to force it to create an "open" tour.

Comment: Hello again. Michael, it seems like something is missing in the code you posted. Could you check it, please? I am not getting the same plot as you, and I can not find the adjmatrix you mention also.

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using?  Versions of Mathematica earlier than 10.0 don't have support for graphs as input to `FindShortestTour`.  You can put `zeroth` itself as an input to `FindShortestTour` in Mathematica 9.0, but the results aren't quite as good.  (I'm actually a little surprised that you can't feed in a list of 3D points in Mathematica 10.0;  I'll have to check it when I get a chance on my work machine tomorrow.)

Comment: Also:  `adjmatrix` is the argument of `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` in my original code.  So you'd want to define `adjmatrix` as the result of the `Outer` command;  redefine any matrix components corresponding to points you didn't want connected;  and then feed that matrix into `WeightedAdjacencyGraph`.  Sorry for the confusion;  an earlier version of my code actually defined this matrix as a separate variable.

Comment: Hi Michael, the biggest problem was that I had not upgraded to Mathematica 10 as you guessed. I did it, and I could finally run your code, which works correctly. Thank you very much for your time.